# Регулярное выражение (-слово, слово- и -слово-)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как сформулировать выражение, чтобы можно было запретить использования тире в данных местах относительно уникального слова

```
-слово, слово- и -слово-
```

Другими словами, регулярку, которая запретить любое нахождение тире относительно уникального слова:

перед словом, после слова и слово между двух тире

Спасибо заранее

Сам попытался, но никак

```
[^-]слово[^-]
```

Comment: Злодейский вопрос: у вас что-то записано через запятую / точку / дефис в базе данных?

Comment: @Etki в том то и дело, теряются межсловные символы после этой регулярки:D
которые необходимо оставить.

Comment: "Оставить" - это значит, что со строкой нужно что-то сделать? Или просто найти все слова? Если просто найти, то тупо: `say $1 while $s =~ /([- ]?\w+[- ]?)/sg;`

Comment: @user200192 пишите впредь в отдельную таблицу. Да и этот проект тоже лучше бы поправить.

Comment: @Etki приходится парсить текст, в котором важны знаки препинания, а после реплейса с регуляркой, регулярка забирает знаки, что фиговато

Comment: А какой у вас диалект регулярных выражений ? у вас работают забегающие и ретроспективные проверки ? Если да, то `(?<!-)слово(?!-)`

Comment: Долго меня доходило в своё время, что и простой текст регулярками тоже парсить не стоит...

Comment: @Mike да, она, спасибо, заверните пожалуйста как ответ

Comment: @PinkTux ну, мой путь не долек в регулярках, поэтому дойдет не скоро:D ну, а вообще, спасибо за помощь. довольно много сэкономлено времени.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В регулярных выражениях для таких случаев есть специальные "не захватывающие" проверки.

```
(?<!-)слово(?!-)
```

Comment: спасибо огромное